# How to stop Google Chrome taking over Internet Explorer?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have been using Google Chrome for years.  Loved it, up until recently.

- I had Adblock installed but ads were coming through and disrupting my work.
- Then Adblock just disappeared from the extensions list.
- I couldn't print emails, it just locked up.
- I went to use Internet Explorer to get some work done and it loaded as Google Chrome.
- I eventually recovered my computer back to a previous date, uninstalled Google Chrome, and went to use IE. 
  After a few minutes of being in IE, it shut down on it's own.
- I clicked on the IE icon and it came up as Google Chrome.
- I went back in and uninstalled GC and now I don't have IE.
- I ran the malware program but says it can't find anything.

Now I have Firefox and hope it doesn't have the same thing happen.

What could have gone wrong and how can i get google chrome, IE working agian?
Thank-you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your installed programs for anything suspicious? A lot of times Anti-Virus software won't pick up things like adware or spyware that's installed itself on your system regardless of how much they are hurting the system. Was Chrome your default browser? If it was being forced open while you were using IE, it may have been because it was your default browser and those pop ups were forcing their way open by opening up a browser session. I'd definitely take a look at what you have installed and remove anything that looks suspicious.

As far as IE goes, in my experience IE is generally difficult to out-rightly remove. You may have a case where a link has been removed here. I would try performing a search for the .exe file (**iexplore.exe**) and see if you can't create a new shortcut to it on your desktop. This may also be a case where you need to reset the settings for IE and Chrome in order to remove any infections or adware that are currently bogging them down. Hope this helps!